# XSLT selecting text that contains strong tags

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to do a transformation on some XML using XSLT.

My xml is;

```
    <body>
      <p>
        <a href="http://www.zz.com/abc/z/0/z3970z88-0475-11dz-8603-00144zeabdc1.html#slide0"></a>
        Some <strong>strong</strong> text
      </p>
    </body>
```

and I want to transform it into;

```
    <body>
      <slideshow data-uuid="z3970z88-0475-11dz-8603-00144zeabdc1/>
      <p>Some <strong>strong</strong> text</p>
    </body>
```

What I have so far is;

```
    <xsl:template match="/body/p[a[substring(@href, string-length(@href) - 6) = '#slide0' and string-length(text()) = 0] and count(*) = 1]">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="a" />
      <xsl:if test="string-length(text()) > 0">
        <p>
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </p>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a[substring(@href, string-length(@href) - 6) = '#slide0' and string-length(text()) = 0]">
      <slideshow>
        <xsl:attribute name="data-uuid">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring(@href, string-length(@href) - 47), '.html#slide0')" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
```

But this only works if the text doesn't have any children, such as the `<strong>` tag or another `<a>` tag.

Does anyone have a solution that will pick it all up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with this XSLT. I'm not sure if if will fit every purpose you can come up with, but it does solve the example you gave here:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/body/p[a]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="a" />
        <p>
            <xsl:copy-of select="./node()[not(self::a)]" />
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a[substring(@href, string-length(@href) - 6) = '#slide0' and string-length(text()) = 0]">
        <slideshow>
            <xsl:attribute name="data-uuid">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring(@href, string-length(@href) - 47), '.html#slide0')" />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </slideshow>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The idea is to copy the contents of the `<p>` tag expect the `<a>` tag.
I changed the condition on the first apply-templates, but you don't have to do this. It just made things more readable for me.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However this doesn't seem to be doing the trick. The response I'm getting is `<body><p><slideshow data-uuid="z3970z88-0475-11dz-8603-00144zeabdc1"/>Some <strong>strong</strong> text</p></body>`  When I try it with just text and no strong tag it works (but it was working for this scenario in my previous solution).

Comment: Do you still use your original condition? Because the count(*) will prevent you from matching the p tag. Why is this count required?

Comment: Thanks, you're right it was the count that was stopping the matching. It seems it wasn't required as other tests passed without it.

Answer (score 0):

In cases where you are transforming only part of your XML, it is usually a good approach to start with the [Identity Template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform)

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" >
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This means, instead of using `xsl:value-of` in your template, use `xsl:apply-templates` and let the identity templ

```
    <xsl:if test="string-length(text()) > 0">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::a)]"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:if>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="p[a[substring(@href, string-length(@href) - 6) = '#slide0' and string-length(text()) = 0] and count(*) = 1]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="a" mode="slideshow" />
        <xsl:if test="string-length(text()) > 0">
            <p>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::a)]"/>
            </p>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a" mode="slideshow">
      <slideshow>
        <xsl:attribute name="data-uuid">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring(@href, string-length(@href) - 47), '.html#slide0')" />
        </xsl:attribute>
      </slideshow>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of a "mode" in the template matching the `a`. This was purely to avoid having to code the long-winded condition twice.

As an aside, you use [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) in the `a` template, to simplify it

```
<xsl:template match="a" mode="slideshow">
      <slideshow data-uuid="{substring-before(substring(@href, string-length(@href) - 47), '.html#slide0')}" />
</xsl:template>
```